# Skew on one side or more

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

I would like to achieve the following:

[image]

As you can see, there are four rectangles with skew applied to the sides so eventually the four can be connected to form a square.

I want to make it dynamic, so one pipe can have one, two, or none skewed sides.

Here is my take on the problem:

```
<div>
  <div class="v vr">
    <div class="pipe">
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="v vl">
    <div class="pipe">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="h ht hle hre">
    <div class="pipe">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="h hb">
    <div class="pipe">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
    .pipe {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(#737373 30%, #cccccc 50%, #737373 70%);
}
.v .pipe {
   background:  linear-gradient(to right, #737373 30%, #cccccc 50%, #737373 70%)
}

.vr{
      min-width: 15px;
    min-height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10014;
    top: 380px;
    left: 840px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 250px;
}

.ht{
      min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10017;
    top: 355px;
    left: 585px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 15px;
  transform: rotate(90);
}


.hb{
      min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10017;
    top: 630px;
    left: 585px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 15px;
  transform: rotate(90);
}

.vl{
      min-width: 15px;
    min-height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10014;
    top: 380px;
    left: 560px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 250px;
}


.ht.hle .pipe:first-child:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999999999;
    background: linear-gradient(#737373 30%, #cccccc 50%, #737373 70%);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform: skew(50deg,0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(50deg,0deg);
    transform: skew(50deg);
}

.ht.hre .pipe:nth-child(1):before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999999999;
  background: linear-gradient(#737373 30%, #cccccc 50%, #737373 70%);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  -ms-transform: skew(28deg,0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(28deg,0deg);
  transform: skew(-50deg);
  //background: white;
}
```

https://codepen.io/HMubaireek/pen/odjWJE

Comment: SO is not coding machine show us your code

Comment: think well, maybe you want something else ?

Comment: @לבנימלכה Here it is: https://codepen.io/HMubaireek/pen/odjWJE

Comment: @TemaniAfif I thought about SVG and I thought CSS would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer to my question:

The HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="v vr  vtre vbre">
    <div class="pipe">
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="v vl vtle vble">
    <div class="pipe">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="h ht hlte hrte">
    <div class="pipe">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="h hb hlbe hrbe">
    <div class="pipe">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.pipe {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(#737373 30%, #cccccc 50%, #737373 70%);
}
.v .pipe {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #737373 30%, #cccccc 50%, #737373 70%);
}

.vr {
  min-width: 15px;
  min-height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 380px;
  left: 840px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 250px;
}

.ht {
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 355px;
  left: 585px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 15px;
}

.hb {
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 640px;
  left: 585px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 15px;
}

.vl {
  min-width: 15px;
  min-height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 380px;
  left: 560px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 250px;
}

.hlte .pipe:first-child:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#737373 30%, #cccccc 50%, #737373 70%);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  -ms-transform: skew(50deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(50deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(50deg);
}

.hrte .pipe:nth-child(1):before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#737373 30%, #cccccc 50%, #737373 70%);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  -ms-transform: skew(28deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(28deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-50deg);
}

.hlbe .pipe:first-child:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#737373 30%, #cccccc 50%, #737373 70%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform: skew(50deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(50deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-50deg);
}

.hrbe .pipe:nth-child(1):before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#737373 30%, #cccccc 50%, #737373 70%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform: skew(28deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(28deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(50deg);
}

.vbre .pipe:first-child:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #737373 30%, #cccccc 50%, #737373 70%);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  -ms-transform: skewY(50deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(50deg, 0deg);
  transform: skewY(50deg);
}

.vble .pipe:first-child:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #737373 30%, #cccccc 50%, #737373 70%);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  -ms-transform: skewY(50deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(50deg, 0deg);
  transform: skewY(-50deg);
}

.vtre .pipe:nth-child(1):before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #737373 30%, #cccccc 50%, #737373 70%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform: skewY(50deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(50deg, 0deg);
  transform: skewY(-50deg);
  //background: white;
}

.vtle .pipe:nth-child(1):before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #737373 30%, #cccccc 50%, #737373 70%);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  -ms-transform: skewY(50deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(50deg, 0deg);
  transform: skewY(50deg);
}
```

https://codepen.io/HMubaireek/pen/odjWJE

The only issue with the above code is that if it's put in a container that has overflow set to hidden, the skews won't appear. I can set the width and margings, but I'm after a more dynamic way.

Note: I won't set it as the accepted answer before a while, maybe better/shorter answer will be introduced.

Edit: Here's a cleaner version with SCSS:

https://codepen.io/HMubaireek/pen/jxbgqG?editors=1100

Answer (score -1):

You can leverage on how [borders work](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) in CSS:

```css
.pipe {
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 6px transparent;
  border-left: solid 6px gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="pipe"></div>
```

Unluckly, there's no a widely supported way to apply a gradient in a CSS border. But you can save your favorite gradient as `.png` and and use [`border-image` property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp) to create the metal effect.

Comment: I'd like to know what's the reason of the downvote. I know it's not a good practice to answer downvoted questions, but I had a fast answer and I took time to write it down, sice it could be useful also for other people googling similar question. It's not a fair behavior

Comment: `I know it's not a good practice to answer downvoted` --> here you are totally wrong, we can answer downvoted questions and we can get upvotes and accepted. I can give you 3 reasons for the downvote 1) you didn't answer the question in any way, he asked about a dynamic way to have 1,2 or 0 skewed part (I only see you have 2 skewed part here) 2) you wrote something wrong, we can use gradient with css border and they are pretty well supported 3) you advise him to use a PNG for the gradient so why not simply create the whole shape in PNG then ? ... and you get only 1 downvote, so it's not bad.

Comment: and the fourth important reason, we don't answer too broad question with 0 effort shown, we flag, we downvote and/or comment. So we downvote such answer to discourage them and to also discourage such question. SO is not a free coding site or a tutorial site

Comment: I think you're not being nice.
1) my answer can be considered partial, I know, but what the user asked was really way complex and what I provided is just a good input 2) gradient borders are not supported, and I took time to make it work but there's no way. Particularly when some of them have to be transparent. If you want, provide a working example and I'll believe you. 3) you can't dynamically set the the height or skewed/not skewed to a static png image. So it's not a solution. What I provided is a partial solution which can be easily extended to what exactly the user wanted

Comment: `I think you're not being nice` --> you asked for the reasons and i gave you 4, so why am not nice? and you got 1 downvote, so what's the issue ? if you are convinced with your answer you may get upvoted ot accepted by the OP. why giving a lot of importance to one isolated vote?